# How do I export data into a CSV in CockroachDB using a custom delimiter?

Tags: cockroachdb

How do I export a cockroach table into a local CSV in CockroachDB using a custom column delimiter?
The following statement does not allow me to specify a custom delimiter
`cockroach sql -e "SELECT * from foo.bar;" --format=csv > my.csv`

Tried using the sql command shown above to obtain a local export.

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB's EXPORT statement allows the specification of a custom delimiter,
e.g.

```
EXPORT INTO CSV 'nodelocal://0/export1/' with delimiter = e'\x01' from table foo;
```

Similarly, to import delimited CSV data:

```
IMPORT INTO foo CSV DATA ('nodelocal://0/export1/...') WITH delimiter = e'\x01';
```

See:
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/export.html
https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v23.1/import-into#import-options